# How to repeat same codes in 10 times and get those results in R?

Tags: r

Here is my code:

```
f.x <- function(x) {
    60*x^3*(1-x)^2
}

x <- seq(0, 1, length=100)
n.samps <- 1000
n <- 0  # counter for accepted
i <- 0  # iterations
samps <- numeric(n.samps)

while (n < n.samps) {
    y <- runif(1)
    i <- i + 1
    u <- runif(1)
    if (u < f.x(y) / 2.0736) {
        n <- n + 1
        samps[n] <- y
    }
}
```

I want to repeat the code above for 10 times, each time an "i" will be produced. I want to take the average of these ten "i". Instead of run the code each time, is there any way I can run one time but get 10 trials?

Comment: Can you give some background about what sort of problem you are trying to solve?  Off the top of my head, a `while` loop _might_ be appropriate, but then again I don't know exactly what you're trying to do here.

Comment: You should group the condition `if (u < (f.x(y) / 2.0736) )`. The order of operations doesn't work the way you first ran it as.

Comment: There is also a stray equals sign at `n <- =n+1`

Comment: Do you need `replicate`?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for editing my codes above. What I am trying to do is to run my code 10 times (“trials”). Then make a table showing the number of "i" required for each trial and the mean number of "i" required for all 10 trial. I could run it ten times and write down "i" each time. But it costs time. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try placing your entire script into a function, and then just call it 10 times from a loop:

```
getValue <- function() {
    x <- seq(0, 1, length=100)
    n.samps <- 1000
    n <- 0  # counter for accepted
    i <- 0  # iterations
    samps <- numeric(n.samps)

    while (n < n.samps) {
        y <- runif(1)
        i <- i + 1
        u <- runif(1)
        if (u < f.x(y) / 2.0736) {
            n <- n + 1
            samps[n] <- y
        }
    }

    return(i)
}
```

**Usage:**

```
result <- replicate(10, getValue())
```

Comment: `replicate(10, getValue())` (p.s. you need to edit your function call).

Comment: @JonathanCarroll I have updated, thanks for the comment.